# The final policy size is bigger than the limit (20480)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Apparently, I reached the limit for the policy of my lambda function which I use with aws-cognito and aws-api-gateway:

`The final policy size is bigger than the limit (20480)`

So my lambda-function is filled with all the permitted endpoints from the api-gateway, f.e.:

```
{
      "Sid": "eff74414-a6bd-4520-bf67-691ced3245d5",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:ID:function:FUNCTION",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:ID:API_ID/*/GET/company"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "6d52e172-84b6-4196-b924-f83b78153bc5",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:ID:function:FUNCTION",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:ID:API_ID/*/GET/companies"
        }
      }
    },
...
```

I know there is a way to consolidate these, using the aws cli, f.e.:

`aws lambda add-permission --function-name 'FUNCTION' --statement-id '7bd8e791-7d28-41d0-9ebd-7e2596574fd5' --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --principal "apigateway.amazonaws.com" --source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:ID:API_ID/*/GET/*/*/*" --source-account "ID" --region 'eu-central-1'`

Although I can add this permission, it's not valid:

> The API with ID API_ID does not include a resource with path ///* having an integration arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:ID:function:FUNCTION on the GET method.

So what can I do to consolidate all my api-permissions?

Comment: It seems like you should be attempting arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:ID:API_ID/*/GET/* not arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:ID:API_ID/*/GET/*/*/*

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found a solution. I set an `Execution role` on each `Integration Request` per resource-method in the API-Gateway.

This execution role needs to have a trusted relationship with the api-gateway - then it will finally work :)

Comment: Can you share a simple example? I'm having the same issue

Comment: in the `IAM`-service you create a role which has f.e. access to your lambda functions.. this role needs to have a trusted relationship with the apigateway. you can create and see that in the role unter "trust relationship"-> `The identity provider(s) apigateway.amazonaws.com`. back in the apigateway manegement, for every endpoint (fe. GET `/my-endpoint`), under "Integration Request" you have to add the ARN of the role from before as "Execution role". arn:aws:iam::100000000000:role/my_role